# Moving controls from one stackpanel to another

Tags: silverlight, stackpanel

I have a bunch of buttons on a stackpanel which I want to programmatically move back and forth on demand. I'm struggling to get the visibility/alignment correct. It appears that the buttons seem to have some setting which occurs when they are initially rendered in the first stackpanel as they don't appear next to each other...and yet, if I add(new Button()) instead of add(btn) I see button images stacked together as I expect.

The buttons are very basic 24x24 with an image. No styling/margins etc.

They are moving from a stackpanel with horizontal alignment to one with vertical.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do stackpane1.Children.Remove(button) and then stackpanel2.children.add(button)

i suspect you must remove it from one then put into another or you will get funny results

Comment: That's what I'm doing...but I just had a DOH moment...some of the buttons had a zero width (i.e. hidden)...sigh...this is fine in horizontal but in vertical...the height was 24 (DOH again)

Comment: Frustrating it took me as long to suss out...changing the (not my original) code to use visibility instead of width=0